# How to handle $0 dollar transactions

Tags: authorize.net

My store offers some 100% off coupons, including shipping. When I try to checkout, it asks for my credit card information. When I try to place the order, it comes back saying "Invalid amount for authorization". I'm using Authorize.net.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to a $0 to confirm credit card validity or creating a token?

Answer (score 4):

By default Magento should display a message saying "No payment information required" if you have the free payment method enabled. This method only displays when there is a $0 checkout.

I'm demonstrating this on a stock Magento 1.8CE, but have used this as far back as 1.2CE:

From System > Configuration > Payment Methods, ensure that the Zero Subtotal Checkout method is enabled:

[image]

And now you need to ensure that you haven't made any template modifications in the checkout theme that would prevent all enabled payment methods from appearing.

Here I'm checking out with a $0.00 item in the cart, and $0.00 flat rate shipping:

[image]